# Facebook php sdk: ask permission with link, not redirect

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I want to change my code so, that first it will check if the user has liked the page. After this (if yes) a question will come up, to accept the terms and if he clicks on the accept button the Facebook permissions request dialog will come up. How can i do this?

The problem is that everytime a user clicks on the app link the $user variable is always false, but he is logged in...

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => 'xxxxx',
'secret' => 'yyyyy',
'baseUrl' => 'http://hosting.address/',
'appBaseUrl' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/app-name/',
'fileUpload' => 'true',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

$params = array(
  scope => 'publish_stream,user_photos',
  redirect_uri => 'http://www.facebook.com/xxxxx?sk=app_yyyyy&app_data=1'
    );

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$app_data = $signed_request["app_data"];


?>
                    <!doctype html>
                    <html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
                    <head>
                    <title>the title</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
<?php if ($user){

    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $likes = $facebook->api("/me/likes/123123123"); //page ID

            if( !empty($likes['data']) ){

                $scope = 'publish_stream,user_photos';
                $scope_params = explode(',',$scope);

                $permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions");
                    if( array_key_exists('publish_stream', $permissions['data'][0]) &&  array_key_exists('user_photos', $permissions['data'][0]) && isset($app_data)) {


                    } else {

echo "<a href=\"/redirect.php\">accept</a></td>";
echo "<a href=\"http://www.facebook.com/pageurl\">deny</a></td>";

                    }
            }else{
                echo "<img width=\"520px\" src=\"no-fan.jpg\" />";
            }

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
        $user = null;
        }
    }

    if ($user) {
        } else {
            $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">top.location.href = "'.$loginUrl .'";</script>';
        }

        ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following this excellent example:

http://www.jelecos.com/default/blog/11-04-18/Facebook_PHP_SDK_Fangate_Creation.aspx

Then on the fanpage.php have your code to ask them to log in.